# Enforce ordering when creating volumes so I can ensure that volume to be extended has unallocated space on the 'right'

Tags: windows, partitioning, ntfs, storage-spaces, virtual-disk

My setup includes a Storage Spaces based virtual disk with 2 NTFS volumes created on top it.

I want to extend only 1 of those volumes and therefore it should always have unallocated space to its `right`.

Is there a way I can enforce that the volume which doesn't have to be extended is on the `left`, so the volume that has to be extended always has unallocated space on it's `right`.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you intend to add more physical diskspace to the Storage Space in the future and then be able to extend the 2nd volume into that additional space ? (Your question doesn't make much sense otherwise).

Well... a Storage Space is just a fancy name for Software Raid and behaves exactly like any other Raid disk setup in Windows.

Windows Disk Administrator and DiskPart always allocate partitions strictly from left to right. And extra space (from a Raid resize) is always added on the right.
(Has to be that way. If it was added to the left the blocknumbering of the already existing partitions would change "on the fly", which would get really messy.)

So: as long as you allocate the "fixed size" partition first you are fine.